# Filter list with particular value of class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, class, c#-4.0

I have a Responsiblity class, which contains some subclasses
Below is the class:-

```
public class Responsibility
{
    private Frequency _FrequencyInfo = new Frequency();
    private ResponsibilityCategory _CategoryInfo = new ResponsibilityCategory();
    private Status _StatusInfo = new Status();

    public int ResponsibilityId { get; set; }
    public string ResponsibilityName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Frequency FrequencyInfo
    {
        get { return _FrequencyInfo; }
        set { _FrequencyInfo = value; }
    }
    public ResponsibilityCategory CategoryInfo
    {
        get { return _CategoryInfo; }
        set { _CategoryInfo = value; }
    }
    public Status StatusInfo
    {
        get { return _StatusInfo; }
        set { _StatusInfo = value; }
    }
}
```

Below is the code i am using to bind the list.But i am getting all the elements of the class.
I just wants two elements from the class.

```
Responsibility newResponsibilty = new Responsibility();
        newResponsibilty.ResponsibilityId = ResponsibilityId;
        new iNGRID_Data.Ops.DataMethods().dbrGetResponsibilityDetailsInSpecifiedResponsibilty(ref newResponsibilty, ResponsibilityId, ref err);
        List<Responsibility> listResponsibilty = new List<Responsibility>();
        listResponsibilty.Add(newResponsibilty);

        JavaScriptSerializer jsonserialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string result = jsonserialize.Serialize(listResponsibilty);
        return Content(result);
```

I want to serialize this list with just 2 objects ResponsibiltyName and Description.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't manually JSON serialize them. Leave it to the framework by returning a Json result. Also you don;t need a list. You could return an anonymous object containing the properties you are interested in:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    Responsibility newResponsibilty = new Responsibility();
    newResponsibilty.ResponsibilityId = ResponsibilityId;
    new iNGRID_Data.Ops.DataMethods().dbrGetResponsibilityDetailsInSpecifiedResponsibilty(ref newResponsibilty, ResponsibilityId, ref err);
    var result = new
    {
        name = newResponsibilty.ResponsibiltyName, 
        description = newResponsibilty.Description
    };
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and inside your AJAX success callback you could read those properties:

```
success: function(result) {
    // you could use result.name and result.description here
}
```

Comment: I think he mend just two properties: ResponsibiltyName and Description.

Comment: I want specific objects of the class not random 2.

Comment: Yeah i might need the 3rd one which is FrequecyId from FrequencyInfo.But for now please help me with the mentioned 2.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I am trying out your solution.